# CSOM: Unable to update or create content type - Value cannot be null. Parameter name: s

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, pnp, office-dev-pnp

When creating or updating content types using PnP/CSOM we are encountering the following error upon executing the query:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: s

The routine had been working for months up until the past couple of days, and only seems to affect a few tenants, works fine for most others.

The content type in question is a relatively simple content type.

Has anyone else come up against this error? Or has any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue because server side breaking changes at Microsoft's end.

Reference - [Breaking change on creating content types using CSOM - Value cannot be null](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/3947)

Temporary fix - Update to the latest version of PnP CSOM/PnP PowerShell (`3.9.1905.2`) from Nuget and then apply the template again, it will fix the issue.